# How can I sum all the values in a row across columns in SQL without specifying all the column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I sum values in a row across columns?

I have an output table [image: output table] from running a query. The output is simply one row and multiple columns. I want to be able to sum all of these values **without having to specify each column name**. How can I do this?

I am already using an aggregate function, `COUNT` to get the data above, which I believe means that I cannot wrap another aggregate function around it.

The structure of the current query is:

```
USE <SOME DM>
SELECT 
   COUNT (CASE WHEN ...)
   COUNT (CASE WHEN ...)
   ...
FROM <SOME TABLE>
```

I am using **MS SQL Server 2012**

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL to do that but that is not actually the issue here.

Comment: Care to tell me what the issue is ?

Comment: If you're generating result like this, why are you doing it to create several columns? Why don't you just have count (...) + count( ...) instead of several columns?

Answer (score 2):

With the help from a little XML and a CROSS APPLY

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,EEE int,EESI int,EETPL int)
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,10,20,30),
(2,40,50,60)

Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast((Select A.* For XML RAW) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Total = Sum(Value)
                      ,Min   = Min(Value)
                      ,Max   = Max(Value)
                      ,Avg   = Avg(Value)
                 From  (
                        Select Value  = attr.value('.','int')          --<< Change to proper data type
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                         Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','OtherCols2Exclude')      --<< Field Name is case sensitive
                       ) S
             ) C
```

**Returns (added min/max/avg just for fun)**

```
ID  Total   Min   Max   Avg
1   60      10    30    20
2   150     40    60    50
```

Comment: Thanks. Have to ask: Is this much code really needed to just sum some values in SQL?

Comment: @Kaleb If you don't want to specify all the fields.  Otherwise you would need to go dynamic.

Comment: @Kaleb The first Cross Apply creates an XML dataset of the row.  The second will pivot the data and aggregate

Comment: @Kaleb . . . Only if you store your data in a non-SQLish way.  You should really have one row per value, with an identifier of what the value is for.  Then the sum would be easy.

Comment: How do I do that?